# Using an EJB inside a JAX-RS resource class in RestEasy?

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I would like to have the following kind of resource class work when deployed under RestEasy in JBoss 6:

```
@Path("Something")
public class Foo {

  @EJB
  private SomeService service

  @GET
  public Object frobnicate() {
    assert service != null;
    // JBoss blows up here

    return result;
  }
}
```

Two questions:

1. It is a limitation of RestEasy, not of the Java EE specification, right, that RestEasy can't inject anything annotated with @EJB?
2. What have people done to work around this limitation?

My developers are about to surge forward with hard-coded JNDI lookups (e.g. context.lookup(someHardCodedNameHere)) because no one can find a workaround to this specification violation at the present time.  I really want to avoid this.

Lastly, I've looked at using CDI, but the story here isn't much better as RestEasy and CDI still aren't talking to each other.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Additional information: I've found http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.2.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#Configuring_Individual_JAX-RS_Resource_Beans, which mentions what is true of the Beta2 release, but in typical JBoss fashion is mum on releases after this point.

Comment: For completeness, here is the skinny on RestEasy CDI integration: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RESTEasy-CDIIntegration.  Short answer: it's not there.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is now supported in JBossAS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JBoss guys tell me this is being worked on on the trunk.  So as of JBoss 6 milestone 3 this is impossible.